# Legal situation for Parkour in the EU

Tags: legality, europe, parkour

I often wonder if it's even legal to practice [Parkour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkour) in the cities of the EU? The runner is kind of trespassing the plots, isn't he?

Comment: Depends on where their doing it. Trespass law is the same regardless of what activity you do.

Comment: Depends on the city... On buildings etc. I doubt the Houses of Parliament would appreciate you running up against their limestone and often in repair walls just so you can do a backflip or something. Even if there is not legislation to stop you.

Comment: As Liam mentioned, it is up to whether you (i.e. the public) have access to the area. Parkour specificly it depends on the particular rules within that area and maybe some kind of "public disturbance" law that might be applied to Parkour.

Comment: Trespass law is very different across the countries of the EU (eg in Scotland we don't really have a trespass law as such) and in many cases stopping parkour is really only done where damage occurs

Comment: I would migrate to Law, but the question is too old. You could ask it on Law if you like.

Comment: Would this be moot for an experienced practitioner, because the police wouldn't be able to keep up or catch them?

Answer (score 6):

This will vary from country to country - I can only speak for the UK.

In practice you are likely to be OK provided you are responsible and apply common sense.

Obviously, if you are on private land without permission you are trespassing and breaking the law. So ask the owner or stick to public land.

If you are on public land you could still cause criminal damage to structures and surfaces. Section 1 of the Criminal Damage Act 1971 states:

> A person without lawful excuse destroys or damages property belonging to another intending to destroy or damage any such property OR BEING RECKLESS AS TO WHETHER ANY SUCH PROPERTY WOULD BE DESTROYED OR DAMAGED SHALL BE GUILTY OF AN OFFENCE.

So check that structures are stable and don't be reckless.

You could also be charged with causing obstruction if you train in areas with heavy footfall, or with breach of the peace if you disturb or frighten other users of the space.

Parkour UK also point out that you have a responsibility to be aware of young children nearby who may be unduly influenced by your actions.

If you don't cause damage or annoy anyone, it's unlikely that the police will become involved. If the police do turn up, just be polite and respectful. In the opinion of one freerunner turned police officer: "I would say there is VERY little they can go on to actually arrest you." (http://goo.gl/jmlYii)

Some people find it helps to be wearing a T-Shirt with the logo of a club or association, to make it clear that you are athletes and not just yobs.

Comment: +1 but can you give a source for the police quote?

Comment: Source added as requested.

Comment: The OP asking about EU and the only answer being about UK is quite ironic :P

Comment: Well, we're still part of the EU for the time being!